# What goes into an Eventlet+Gunicorn worker thread?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, gunicorn, eventlet

If I deploy Django using Gunicorn with the Eventlet worker type, and only use one process, what happens under the hood to service the 1000 (by default) worker connections? What parts of  Django are copied into each thread? Are any parts copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `workers = 1` in your gunicorn configuration, two processes will be created: 1 master process and 1 worker process.

When you use `worker_class = eventlet`, the simultaneous connections are handled by green threads. Green threads are not like real threads. In simple terms, green threads are functions (coroutines) that `yield` whenever the function encounters I/O operation.

So nothing is copied. You just need to worry about making every I/O operation 'green'.

Comment: So does this mean that I have one instance of Django held in memory, shared by all threads?

Comment: there is no thread. When you use eventlet it will actually create greenthreads. It's good when your api is IO bound in other words when it doesn't consume lots of time calculating. Everything runs in a single thread asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, it does mean that you will have one instance of Django shared by all green threads.